# Numeric Comparison of DataGridView Cell Value Evaluates Incorrectly

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, casting, case-statement

I want to put background color on datagridview cell if the Temperature is >=7.

I'm using below code and it's working fine for temperature 7.01 to 9.99 but if the temperature is 10.01 and above, background color is not showing. Appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub ReeferDGridview_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles ReeferDGridview.CellFormatting
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = Me.ReeferDGridview.Columns("Temperature").Index Then
        If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim LStatus As String = e.Value.ToString

            Select Case LStatus
                Case Is >= 7
                    Me.ReeferDGridview.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Maroon
                    Me.ReeferDGridview.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
                Case Else
                    Me.ReeferDGridview.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Nothing
                    Me.ReeferDGridview.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black

            End Select

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Switch Option Strict On - that will guide you towards the errors you have in your code

Comment: I already Switch Option Strict On still same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you are putting the numeric value from your grid into a `String` variable and then using that to compare to a numeric value in your `Case` statement.

Important Note: If you have `Option Strict` switched `On`, your code will not compile because it alerts you to the fact that you are doing this.

So when your code runs it is actually comparing a string to another string. The > (greater than) operator will test by alphabetical order or character code value order (depending on the Option Compare setting)

So your code is actually doing this

```
"9.99" > "7" 'evaluates to True
"10" > "7" 'evaluates to False
```

To fix this you just need to use a numeric type for `LStatus`:

```
Dim LStatus As Single = CSng(e.Value.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I add below code:

```
Dim LStatus As String = e.Value.ToString
Dim number As Double
Double.TryParse(LStatus, number)
```

Comment: You doing extra converting with no reason. Use `Dim number As Double = DirectCast(e.Value, Double)`. Because you know original type of the `Cell.Value`